# Как повесить обработчик на нажатие кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Как повесить обработчик на нажатие кнопки? VS2012, C#, WPF.

Как в этом обработчике изменить текст другого элемента в окне?

Comment: Что не так-то? ю

Comment: Какой элемент? Контрол? Текст блок? Текст бокс? Лабель? Прямоугольный квадрат??? Ванга в отпуске.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик да хоть какого, блжад. Вопрос откройте.

Comment: Вам уже [ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458199/185848) [RadikSt](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190040/radikst), вполне сносно. При условии если у элемента есть св-во **Text** и оно типа **String**

Comment: И что за манера задавать вопрос, по которому [Яндекс](http://www.yandex.ru/yandsearch?clid=9582&text=Как%20создать%20событие%20Click%20WPF&l10n=ru) выдает ответ в первом же результате

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик во-первых, у меня это не нашлось, во-вторых - таких вопросов на so море. Не хотите - не читайте. Если читаете - попробуйте отвечать, а не умничать.

Comment: @SmitJohnth да никто не будет Вам отвечать на вопрос, который не содержит проблему и сводится к руководству. Причем описанному в первых двадцати страницах книги или спокойно находится по поисковику в виде гайда в картинках.

Comment: " который не содержит проблему и сводится к руководству." - што? "Причем описанному в первых двадцати страницах книги" - какой именно?

Comment: какой смысл переоткрывать этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

После двойного щелчка мыши по кнопке, создается подписчик на событие. Туда нужно добавить свой код.

xaml:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click"/>
```

cs:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   //Сюда пишешь свой обработчик. Например изменение Label Свой-во текст.
   myLabel.Content= "Твой текст";
 }
```

Comment: "После двойного щелчка мыши по кнопке, создается подписчик на событие. " - а вот и фиг.

Comment: Добавь вручную тег в кнопку Click="Button_Click", должно получится <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="362,23,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

Comment: В код формы добавь                                                                     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //Сюда пишешь свой обработчик. 
    }

Comment: А без ручного добавления можно? Почему двойной щелчок не работает?

Comment: Попробуй пересоздать кнопку и еще раз щелкнуть. Если не поможет, то добавляй код вручную.

Comment: "Почему двойной щелчок не работает" да потому что среда не знает твоих мыслей! Может ты хочешь событие двойного клика или MouseDown.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик не умничай, блин, прочти ответ который сам редактировал - там про двойной щелчок было... Откуда я знаю, может у меня со студией что-то не то.